# Duplicate web parts shown in SharePoint publishing page layouts and page instances on feature

Tags: layout, web-parts, publishing

I have created custom layout  with a web part zone and a customer web part in it.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="NvRDDevliverable2" runat="server" title="Zone 2">
<ZoneTemplate>
          <DeliverableMapping:DeliverableMapping runat="server" 
                  ID="DevliverableOwnership" Description="Ownership and Timing" 
                  Title="Ownership and Timing " __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 
                   __WebPartId="{804C2865-8F61-4828-8460-312ABB3DFA9A}" WebPart="true" 
                   __designer:IsClosed="false" partorder="2"></DeliverableMapping:DeliverableMapping>
         </ZoneTemplate>
      </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

When I tried to update the layout, duplicate web parts show up on all page instances. 
How to avoid this issue?